# Simulate Form Post in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an HTML form (form action="https:..." method="post"). I want to handle the post in PHP. How do I simulate the form post in PHP? So, instead, I will have (form action="helper.php") a and helper.php will post the form data.

Comment: Keep in mind that $_POST is just an array, so you could always manually populate it at the beginning of your script if you just want to use this to test something. Otherwise, use curl.

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with the cURL extension. See http://php.net/curl

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy to create [php form](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/php-forms.html) particulary you have data product than you shouls only to download php form and install options for it.